# How can I get the previous version of a particular file currently in the SVN working folder using SharpSVn DLL in C#.net?

Tags: c#, svn

I wish to display the currently checked out file and the same file in its immediate previous version so that the user can get a chance to compare the two files manually and later merge the changes to the Subversion(SVN) repository. Is there a sample code to do that using Sharpsvn DLL ?

Comment: if you use TortoiseSVN it does have a diff function.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I have tried TortoiseSVN's 'diff with previous version' . But my aim is to have a similar feature in my C# application that I am currently working on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That is what svn diff is for.

Edit: Look into `SvnClient.DiffSummary`.

Comment: Thank you for this information. 
My aim is to display current (Head) revision and the previous revision of the file in adjusent edit boxes as nicely done in TortoiseSVN.